# How to create a sequence without a model with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd, factory-bot

I want to create a sequence without creating a model `Foo`:

```
let( :foo_id ){ sequence...? }
```

The following code works, but creates a model `Foo`.

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :id do |i| 
    i 
  end

  factory :foo do
    id
    text { 'Text'}
  end
end
```

In spec:

```
let( :foo ){ create :foo )
...
# Using foo.id
```

How to create a numeric sequence without a model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FactoryGirl does not support this, but [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org/) does.

Take a look at [this documentation](http://www.fabricationgem.org/#!sequences).

```
Fabricate.sequence
# => 0
# => 1
# => 2
```

If you place such a statement in your `let`, you will get a new number every time:

```
let( :foo ){ Fabricate.sequence(:my_id) )
```